# Dynamic Programming - minimize the sum of the array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

My problem is: given an array of negative and positive integers. You are given value j to jump and r to rest. After each jump, you need to rest for r steps. Moreover, you are allowed to move 1 more step forward even when you have the ability to jump. The problem is to minimize the sum of the array.

Ex.1 `r = 2, j = 2,  [5, 3, -4, -2, 1, 2, 3]` =>  -4 + -2 + 3 = -3 (Jump 5, 3, Rest -4,-2, Jump 1,2, Rest 3)

Ex.2 `r = 2, j = 3,  [90, 91, 92, -2, 3, 55, 3]` =>  -2 + 3 + 55 + 3 = 59 (Jump 90,91,92 Rest -2,3,55,3)

---

My Idea: I decided to use DP to solve this. This is my pseudocode.

```py
def minimalSum (MIN, array, jump, rest, steps_left_to_jump, i):
    if MIN[i] is not empty:
        return MIN[i]
    if i == len(array) - 1:
        MIN[i] = array[i]
    else:
        if steps_left_to_jump == 0:
            if i == 0:
                MIN[i] = minimalSum(MIN, array, jump, rest, rest - 1, jump)
            else:
                if i + jump + 1 < len(array):
                    MIN[i] = array[i] + minimalSum(MIN, array, jump, rest, rest - 1, i + jump + 1)
            o1 = array[i] + minimalSum(MIN, array, jump, rest, 0, i + 1)
            if MIN[i] is not None:
                if o1 < MIN[i]:
                    MIN[i] = o1
            else:
                MIN[i] = o1
        else:
            MIN[i] = array[i] + minimalSum(MIN, array, jump, rest, steps_left_to_jump - 1, i + 1)
    return MIN[i]
```

`MIN` is array used to store best sums.

The problem that it does not work for all inputs, can you help me spot where I am going wrong. Consider the example
`r = 2, j = 2 , [2 ,-2 ,-3,1 ,3 ,4]`. The answer should be 1 (Visit 2, -2, Jump -3, Rest 4) 2-2-3+4 = 1, but my program outputs 5

Comment: *"The problem that it does not work for all inputs"* - which inputs? Give us an example, with the expected result and actual result. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @kaya3 I cant see the inputs for which it doesn't work for, but I know its an input of at least 10 numbers

Comment: Where do you define `discomfort`? What is it?

Comment: It's your code, you choose what inputs to provide it with. If this is for a web challenge where the site judges your code based on hidden test-cases, then invent a test-case yourself for which your code gives the wrong answer.

Comment: Sorry that should be array

Comment: @kaya3 r = 2, j = 2 , discomfort = {2 ,-2 ,-3,1 ,3 ,4}.  the answer is 1, but my program returns 5

Comment: OK, now edit the question to include your example, with an explanation of why 1 is the correct answer.

Comment: What is the difference between a rest and a jump?

Comment: You can do a regular move whenever you want, but when you jumped you need to visit next ```rest``` numbers in array

Comment: The problem statement is not clear. Could you please link to the question? Or better, post the exact problem statement.

Comment: What are ALL the sample inputs to the function, exactly? (specify value used for MIN, array,jump....) It might be easier to understand where you whent wrong if you explain your code with comments (e.g. what is o1, what is i,....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be in this line:

```py
if i == 0:
    MIN[i] = minimalSum(MIN, array, jump, rest, rest - 1, jump)
```

This prevents you from ever choosing Visit whenever i is 0, since you ALWAYS jump in your first step. I don't know about your full code, but this part should be:

```py
if i == 0:
    MIN[i] = min(minimalSum(MIN, array, jump, rest, rest - 1, jump) , # case where you jump at 0
                 array[0] + minimalSum(MIN, array, jump, rest, 0, 1)  # case where you visit index 0
                )
```

Also, your code  give you an out-of-bounds error if `jump>len(MIN)-1`.  If this condition  is true, you know you should ALWAYS visit.
Given all of this, I'm going to write the recursive formula, you can then memoize it:

```
def opt_sum(array, r, j):
    if j > len(array)-1:
        return sum(array)  # cannot jump, return sum of full array
    else:
        visit_val = array[0] + opt_sum(array[1:], r, j)  # best sum if you choose to visit index 0
        jump_val = (
                sum(array[j:j+r])     # total mandatory resting visits
                + opt_sum(array[j+r:], r, j)  # the optimal sum of the subarray
                )                             # starting after the rest
        return min(visit_val, jump_val)  # return best of both policies
```